# Should the Jira assignee change for testing?

Tags: testing, bitbucket, devops, jira, agile

We currently have `Reporter` and `Assignee` fields for' Jira' stories. For example, let's say we move from the `Code review` column to the `Ready for testing` column. Should the tester then come in, delete the original coder's name from the story, and put his name as the assignee? I'm used to `Azure Devops` where if a tester comes in, I believe there are fields for multiple assignees (Assignee field and QA Tester field).

But I had this tester remove my name, so in my standup, it suddenly looked like I had no work on the board (nor any work completed), and I had trouble finding where the heck my story went. It seems incorrect to delete the original coder's name and then put the tester's name just for some smoke testing tracking (at the expense of engineering tracking)- but maybe I'm incorrect? What's the way to go around this in `Jira` where there's just one `Assignee` field?

Comment: I think this is more suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find it useful to have an easily readable history of who worked on a ticket you can use a combination of custom fields and automation to achieve it.

For example, you could add a custom field called 'developer'. Then, add a transition rule that when a ticket is transitioned to `Ready for testing` the assignee field gets copied into the developer custom field.